Is it possible that prior to the Big Bang, space and time were separate and were joined as a result of the Big Bang?
Is it possible space and time were separate prior to the Big Bang and the explosion was a result of their collision?

We have no idea.

I am not aware of any existing physical theory that even has the possibility to address this question

This is an extremely poor question for more than one reason.

No. Both space and time are defined through emergent classical phenomena in this era of the universe. Without the existence of these emergent phenomena none of these terms make any sense whatsoever.

Despite the name (which was originally intended as an insult), the Big Bang isn't like an explosion. In an explosion, a relatively cold thing gets hot very quickly. In the Big Bang, the universe starts very hot, and gets cold quickly.

In classical and non-relativistic mechanics time is treated seperately from space.  With the advent of relativity space and time are joined into spacetime.
Both in special and general relativity it is impossible for spacetime to be seperated.  So the question can be reframed as whether relativity was true at the time of the big bang?
In a 2006 Scientific American article by Gabriele Veneziano we get this tidbit:

One of the assumptions--that relativity theory is always valid--is
questionable. Close to the putative singularity, quantum effects must
have been important, even dominant. Standard relativity takes no
account of such effects, so accepting the inevitability of the
singularity amounts to trusting the theory beyond reason. To know what
really happened, physicists need to subsume relativity in a quantum
theory of gravity.

Veneziano is noted as "the father of string theory in the late 1960s" and in the article it becomes the case that if we make assumptions about the fundamental nature of the planck scale and the nature of strings we can have some way of preserving time, making the universe eternal.
Hawking made the case highlighted in a 2014 article that time and space do seperate at the big bang singularity, giving time a beginning in space. Meaning that a seperation of spacetime in relativity means it is meaningless to talk about time before the big bang.
Hawking's no boundary proposal relies on the idea of imaginary time. This proposal makes use of the Wick Rotation to change the signature of the metric from (-,+,+,+) to (+,+,+,+). This rotation is used to relate different branches of physics like statistical mechanics and quantum mechanics and different equations like the Schrodinger equation and the Heat equation.
Hawking states in his article regarding imaginery time:

One can picture it in the following way. One can think of ordinary,
real, time as a horizontal line. On the left, one has the past, and on
the right, the future. But there's another kind of time in the
vertical direction. This is called imaginary time, because it is not
the kind of time we normally experience. But in a sense, it is just as
real, as what we call real time.
The three directions in space, and the one direction of imaginary
time, make up what is called a Euclidean space-time. I don't think
anyone can picture a four dimensional curve space. But it is not too
difficult to visualise a two dimensional surface, like a saddle, or
the surface of a football.

These proposals are both radical in their own right, but it highlights that as you approach the high energy densities of a singularity, there has to be some change in the mechanics of the physics.  In time we might be able to tease out more details of the early universe to give an indication of which approach to take, but presently its still speculation.

Addendum: Accepting imaginary time as physical also adds some physical meaning to what happens inside a black hole. Inside a black hole the gravitational time dilation becomes imaginary, which could suggest that somehow reaching the interior of a black hole would allow unidirectional movement across the imaginary time "axis". Of course without quantum gravity we don't really know what's going on inside a black hole which makes that partly speculative but the math in the Schwarzschild metric seems to suggest the possibility.

Anybody who lives at the bottom of the ocean will find these theorists laughable in their naive understanding of the world. Of course there are plenty of systems that are NOT relativistic. Water is one of them. Earth's surface is another. There is not even Newtonian physics on Earth's surface. The closest humans have ever gotten to experiencing Newtonian physics is on board of the ISS (and in various other spacecraft). Relativity requires in addition that we are talking about the empty physical vacuum. That is the only system for which it is valid.
